# Extending line to the nearest polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, pyqgis, polygon, line

I need to extend several lines to its intersection with another feature class (polygons).

In order to know the distance from the road to the building facade (in several points of the road) I created perpendicular lines to the street segments each 5 meters and I want to extend the line, until the building facade.

I have tried the `'Extend tool'` in QGIS but it only let me extend them to the buildings if they are in the same layer (if they are lines and then merging the building lines with the perpendicular lines). However, I do not consider it as the best method because if all lines (building lines and perpendicular lines) are in the same layer perpendicular lines could just intersect themselves (and not the building lines).

Is there any way in ArcGIS Desktop I can make those lines extend until they intersect with the buildings as a separated feature class?

Is there any way I can make it in QGIS?

If any of you know a script or something I could also try using Python.

[image: example]

Comment: It is recommended to keep focused on GIS SE, therefore choosing one tool/software/library will be highly appreciated. Moreover, when referring to Pythonic Possibilities the GIS SE community expects to see at least some attempt made by the author to resolve his/her problem. Otherwise your question might be closed because it can be too broad or either opinion-based. Also it is not yet clear to me what to do with those short lines that are placed where the roads overlap.

Comment: How did you create these 5m lines? Can you not make these longer? Then erase the lines using the building facade polygon to get length of the line?

Comment: For instance in QGIS, I can suggest the following workflow (1) `'Extend lines'` (2) `'Difference...'` your facades and result of (1) and then (3) `'Join attributes by location'` using `touches`.